# Where to find or download USB Driver folder?

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, usb-drive, nexus-7

I am following the guide on http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html for installing driver software so I can run applications on my actual Nexus 7. I got to this step in the directions(ironic cause its also step 7)

```
7.Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in <sdk>\extras\google\usb_driver\.)
```

I tried doing the following 
[image]However when I hit browse, I got a dialog prompt saying "Windows could not find driver software for your device".  The Android documentation stated that "The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver\". When I navigated into \extras\google, this is all i saw 
[image]

Is there anyway I could download the usb_driver directory manually? The sdk came along with the Android Studio download. I don't know why that usb_driver directory isn't there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue was that I jumped ahead and skipped the most important step, downloading the Google USB Driver......[image]

Comment: If its installed correctly then check these two locations->            
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver"      or                     "C:\Users\musab\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\google\usb_driver"

Answer (score 2):

After installing the Google USB Driver package, Go to Device manager and search for your connected android phone and give the following path for android driver.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

Answer (score 1):

But by me, after downloading the SDK Tools/Google USB drive (not "Extra" anymore), when I try to update the driver (from device manager: Portable Devices/Galaxy J7 Nxt) it says: the best drivers for your device are already installed.

windows 10 / android 6 marshmalow installed.

phone: android J7 Nxt 
driver installed: SAMSUNG Mobile MTP Device